# Appending older posts is repeating returned records

Tags: php, sql, json, ajax, mysqli

So I'm creating a feed for users and I'm trying to get content older than the first two posts that are called on page load. What I'm getting with the below code when scrolling down is repeating records of the first two results over and over again. All I need it to do is append any data that's older than the last_id, which I'm getting perfectly through Json.

Also I need the DESC LIMIT but when I added DESC LIMIT $last_id into my query, I wasn't getting any JSON response data at all so I had to take it out.

**AJAX FUNCTION**

The last_id is caught and sent back to my php page so $_POST['last_id'] on first scroll will be updated from 0 to the last inserted record. - Tested

```
    <script>
    var last_id = 0;
    function loadAll () {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'commentedoncontent.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: { last_id: last_id},
    success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.posts, function(i, response) {
    });
    last_id = data.last_id;
    }
    })
    }
    </cript>
```

**PHP**

My last id is coming through json fine. I don't know however what's going on this side. I need the results in DESC order and tried adding DESC LIMIT $last_id and my feed just vanished completely and no json array is returned

```
     $last_id=(isset($_POST['last_id']) && $_POST['last_id'] > 1)
     ? $last_id = $_POST['last_id'] : $last_id = 0;
     $user1_id=$_SESSION['id'];
     $query = "SELECT *
     FROM streamdata m
     INNER JOIN streamdata_feedback t1 
     WHERE 
     m.streamitem_id=t1.feedback_streamid
     AND
     t1.feedback_userid=$user1_id
     AND
     t1.feedback_rating=1 
     ORDER BY t1.feedback_id  DESC LIMIT 2,2 ";
     $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die('Error: ' .mysqli_error($mysqli));
     $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

     $json = array(); 
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

     $last_id = $row['streamitem_id'];
     $json[] = array(
    'streamitem_id' => $row['streamitem_id'],
    'streamitem_content' => $row['streamitem_content'],
     );
     }
     echo json_encode(array('posts' => $json, 'last_id' => $last_id));
```

Am I best using the returned data.last_id feeding it into a new function to json  and then doing something like `m.streamitem_id < $last_id` in a new query in a separate php page?

Comment: If you pass 2 arguments to LIMIT, the first argument is an offset of the number of rows to start from, not the ID of the last record. IDs don't have to be continuous, and you're returning the records in reverse order, so passing last_id to the LIMIT clause doesn't really make a lot of sense. I think you're probably better saying WHERE t1.feedback_id < $last_id LIMIT 2. If there's no last_id, you could just leave that clause out of the query.

Comment: how would I do the if Last_id=0 and leave it from the query..As it starts at zero and gets the first two records that way..and from then on it it will have the last_id passed to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of else if on the old last_id, with the help of  @ADyson and his helpful comment, I was able to contrast this much easier.

```
if ($last_id==0){
$query = "SELECT *
FROM streamdata m
JOIN streamdata_feedback t1 
WHERE 
m.streamitem_id=t1.feedback_streamid
AND
t1.feedback_userid=$user1_id
AND
t1.feedback_rating=1 
ORDER BY t1.feedback_id DESC LIMIT 2";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));

}else{
$testa=$_POST['last_id'];
$query = "SELECT *
FROM streamdata m
JOIN streamdata_feedback t1 
WHERE 
t1.feedback_id < $testa
AND
m.streamitem_id=t1.feedback_streamid
AND
t1.feedback_userid=$user1_id
AND
t1.feedback_rating=1 
ORDER BY t1.feedback_id DESC LIMIT 2";
}
```

Comment: is that actually what you did? The two queries are identical. Is it a copy/paste error? :-)

Comment: They're not identical. the bottom one has the streamitem_id less than condition. and they're in a if else statement too. Works perfect now.

Comment: sorry, shouldn't be looking at it last thing on a Sunday, should I lol. You could duplicate a lot less code here by using your if/else only to generate the extra line in there WHERE clause, rather than writing 90% of the statement twice.

Comment: hmmm. Could you show me how to do this. I'm very interested in that idea. Thanks @ADyson

Comment: made a separate answer to demonstrate

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more streamlined version of your answer, with more maintainable code, and no duplication:

```
$query = "SELECT *
  FROM streamdata m
  JOIN streamdata_feedback t1 
WHERE";

if ($last_id != 0) {
  $query .= " t1.feedback_id < $last_id AND";
}

$query .= " m.streamitem_id = t1.feedback_streamid AND
  t1.feedback_userid = $user1_id
  AND
  t1.feedback_rating = 1 
ORDER BY t1.feedback_id DESC LIMIT 2";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Comment: I've up voted just because it's not the actual answer to the question by a sub answer. But thank you so much. I like this and will use this technique to cut down future code. @ADyson, you've been a fantastic help and I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @Gateway no problem, happy to help :-)